# Importing CSV file into cockroachdb , error in date time format

Tags: csv, timestamp, sql-insert, cockroachdb

I am importing a CSV file into a table in cockroachdb with the following command:

```
\| IFS=","; while read a1 a2; do echo "INSERT INTO sales VALUES ($a1, $a2);"; done < sales.csv;
```

My csv file has only two rows:

```
ID, time
14,2013-02-17 05:39:36.710332000
```

Data types of the columns:

```
first column: NUMBER(10, 0)
second column: TIMESTAMP
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "5"

INSERT INTO sales VALUES (14, 2013-02-17 05:39:36.710332000
                                         ^
```

Based on the [CockroachDB documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/timestamp.html), I think I am using the correct `TIMESTAMP` format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF`).

Any suggestions?

I have also tried to change the data in second column without milliseconds, like

```
2013-02-17 05:39:36
```

but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your timestamp string:

```
jordan@:26257/test> INSERT INTO derp VALUES (1, 2013-02-17 05:39:36.710332000);
invalid syntax: statement ignored: syntax error at or near "5"
jordan@:26257/test> INSERT INTO sales VALUES(1, '2013-02-17 05:39:36.710332000')
INSERT 1
```

You can modify your script to do that too, like so:

```
\| IFS=","; while read a1 a2; do echo "INSERT INTO sales VALUES ($a1, '$a2');"; done < sales.csv;
```

Comment: This input file is shrunk only to one row for testing, In that case I have to change it for all the rows in the original file.

Comment: You can change your input script to quote `$a2` as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed command to ...  ($a1, '$a2') ...   the error is pq: name ""ID"" is not defined, "" are doubled on the first column name

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like your script is trying to insert the header row of your CSV. Try deleting that row from the CSV, or adjusting your script to skip the first line of the CSV.

Comment: I removed the header and reran the command  ... ($a1, '$a2') ..., it is still not working, I got this error: INSERT INTO sales VALUES (14, e'2013-02-17 05:39:36.710332000\r');

Comment: works if I put ' inside the CSV file for only the timestamp column and use ... ($a1, $a2) ...